# English translation of German conversation in Kelly’s Heroes

Tags: dialogue, translation, kellys-heroes

Just before Oddball’s tanks launched a surprise attack on a railway yard in France while on the way to meet up with Kelly and his platoon, the two German soldiers in the picture who were on top of a railway car were having a short conversation. What were they saying?

[image]

Comment: If you provide a link to said scene, I'll gladly translate it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/nC4lVoCFZvk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even as a German native, I have a hard time understanding what the two soldiers were saying. My guess is that they took American actors with very little proficiency in German.
After listening to the dialogue several times, I *think* that this is what is being said.

Soldier 1: Hey, Franz.

Soldier 2:  It‘s really hot. (?)

Soldier 1: There‘s really nothing you can do about it.

Soldier 2: Yes, you're right.

The first half isn't easy to understand, and this is particularly true for the first line of Soldier 2.